# Detached Exception Passed to Persist When Hibernate Evict Method is Used

Tags: hibernate, jpa, seam

When updating a Managed Entity data is not directly reflect to DB, so I'm using evict in Hibernate. The exception I'm getting is the detached entity passed to persist.

```
MobeeAgent agent= agentsList.get(rowIndex);
BeanUtils.copyProperties(agent, doMobeeAgent);
agentsList.set(rowIndex, agent);
((Session)getEntityManager().getDelegate()).evict(agentsList.get(rowIndex));
```

Regards

Nag.

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Format your code and indent it properly. Use proper English words and punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

"*detached entity passed to persist*" means that you're trying to call `persist()` with an entity that is considered by Hibernate as already existing (because it already has an ID, or a non-zero @Version property). *persist()* is used to *create* a *new* entity. If you want to *update* and *existing* entity, `merge()` must be used.

Comment: thank you Nizet,Im using merge changes will be reflect to Db ,i want to remove change object from first level cache